# JavaScript Continously check if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, intervals

What is a good way to continously check if a Checkbox is checked or not.

This checks wether it is checked or not.

I thought of creating an interval but I do not like that.

```
if(checkboxPencil.checked)
```

Comment: Use Event handler. Bind `change` event.

Comment: Why check it continuously, when you can get an event when it changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two choices:

1. Use an event handler for the `change` event
2. Poll using `setInterval` or similar

Of the two, #1 is by far the better option unless you have a really good reason for not using the event.

Here's an example of #1:

```js
// The selector can be any valid CSS selector identifying the checkbox
document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log("New value is: " + this.checked);
}, false);
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  Checkbox
</label>
```

Comment: Is it better to use `document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").` than something like `document.getElementById()`

Comment: @Micheasl: Neither is better, it's purely how you want to identify the element. If the element has an ID, then use `getElementById`. But giving all of your elements IDs gets to be a mess fairly quickly. `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are more flexible, letting you use any valid CSS selector to find the element(s).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the the [`onchange` Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) which is supported in all modern browsers.

Whatever functionality you wish to do if the checkbox is checked, you'll be able to do from an `onchange` Event handler. For example:

```js
function changeStatus(o) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerText = o.checked;
}
```

```html
<input id="check" type="checkbox" onchange="changeStatus(this)" />
<span id="status">false</span>
```